# File.Move Not Working, No Error

Tags: c#, .net

I'm running into some issues trying to move flat HTML files around on a server.

In short, the process says that it should take whatever file is currently in the newpath (if there is one) and move it to the backup folder. Then take the file in the old path and move it to the new path. Then it checks to see if it was successful (i.e. does the newpath exist) and if it wasn't, it replaces the backup. I've pasted the method below for your viewing pleasure.

```
    public bool MoveContent(string oldPath, string newPath, string backupDirectoryPath, out string backupPath)
    {
        backupPath = String.Empty;
        var oldFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(oldPath);
        var newFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(newPath);
        var newDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(newFilePath);

        // If the file we're moving doesn't exist, fail.
        if (!File.Exists(oldFilePath))
            throw new InvalidPathException(oldFilePath);

        // If no destination is found, fail.
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newDirectory))
            throw new InvalidPathException(newFilePath);

        if (!Directory.Exists(newDirectory))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(newDirectory);

        var backupPhysicalPath = String.Empty;
        // If there is a file in our destination, back that one up.
        if (File.Exists(newFilePath) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(backupDirectoryPath))
        {
            var backupFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(backupDirectoryPath);
            var backupDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(backupFilePath);

            // If the backup destination doesn't exist, fail.
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(backupDirectory))
                throw new InvalidPathException(backupDirectory);

            if(!Directory.Exists(backupDirectory))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(backupDirectory);

            var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newFilePath);
            var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(FileHelpers.TempFileDateFormat);
            var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(newFilePath);
            // Example Result: hardware-2015-01-30-08-35-26-475.html
            backupPath = backupDirectoryPath.Replace(fileName, fileName + "-" + currentDateTime);
            backupPhysicalPath = String.Format("{0}\\{1}-{2}{3}", backupDirectory, fileName, currentDateTime, fileExtension);

            // If there is already a file in our backup destination, fail.
            if (File.Exists(backupPhysicalPath))
                throw new InvalidPathException(backupPhysicalPath);

            // Backup the file that currently exists in our new destination.
            File.Move(newFilePath, backupPhysicalPath);
        }

        // Move our file to the new destination.
        File.Move(oldFilePath, newFilePath);

        // Return false if the new file doesn't exist.
        if (!File.Exists(newFilePath))
        {
            // If we made a backup, return the backup to the original loction, since there's nothing in the destination.
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(backupPhysicalPath) && File.Exists(backupPhysicalPath))
            {
                File.Move(backupPhysicalPath, newFilePath);
            }

            throw new Exception(String.Format("Failed to move content. OldPath: '{0}'; NewPath: '{1}'; BackupPath: '{2}'", oldFilePath, newFilePath, backupPhysicalPath));
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Here's an example of the parameters being passed in:

```
oldPath: "/client/content/en/unpublished/Anpan.html"
newPath: "/client/content/en/Anpan.html"
backupDirectoryPath: "/client/content/en/backups/Anpan.html"
```

The problem that I'm running into is that sometimes the backup file will be made (it will move from newpath to backuppath), but it won't move from oldpath to newpath.

I've been unable to actually reproduce the issue as it happens so infrequently and without any exceptions being thrown, but the symptoms exist (I can see the files on the filesystem when the client reports the issue) and it's been reported multiple times.

I put some logging around it and wrapped the entire method in a try/catch. It never fails unexpectedly (except when I specifically throw the InvalidPathException). There is nothing in my logs when it happens.

Can anyone help me to diagnose this issue, or tell me if I'm doing something very wrong in my method that would cause the problem?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Does something else have the file open, like the indexing service?

Comment: @RonBeyer I figured if there was something else with the file open File.Move would throw an error, right? I haven't seen anything opening the files, but I haven't run into the error myself either.

Comment: Did you try to follow this code with a debugger? Usually this is the easiest way to find these kind of problems

Comment: @Drayvock see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx , specifically where it says: *If you try to move a file across disk volumes and that file is in use, the file is copied to the destination, but it is not deleted from the source.* It also doesn't say anything about throwing exceptions if the file is open.

Comment: @Steve I have followed with a debugger, but it is always successful for me. I haven't been able to reproduce the error, but all the symptoms of it exists.

Comment: @RonBeyer I don't think this is the issue. The problem is that there is no more file in the newPath. It is successfully moved to the backupPath. But the oldPath is never moved to the newPath, leaving the newPath empty.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility it hasn't completed moving the file before you are moving it again?

Comment: @JevgeniGeurtsen Will File.Move return before it's completed moving the file?

Comment: No it won't. But it uses the MoveFile function API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx which does return a boolean on completion.

Comment: Is it possible that this `MoveContent` could be called from more than one thread?

Comment: Too add, does it only happen to large(r) files?

Comment: @RonBeyer No, I don't do any multi-threading with this. It's all done within a single HTTP request.

Comment: Its not possible to get two requests at the same, or nearly the same time?

Comment: @JevgeniGeurtsen The majority of files that this is happening do are 5-6 line text files that are less than 1kb.

Comment: @RonBeyer Technically speaking, yes. But our interface discourages it. I'll definitely keep an eye out for that though, and try to simulate it in some tests.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this behavior. Is it an idea to use `File.Copy` and `File.Delete` instead of `File.Move`?

Comment: Hi. Did you find the reason why your issue was happening or any solution? I'm running across the same issue

Comment: @MariFaleiros My apologies, I never did figure out what happened here. The company I was working for at the time got acquired by it's competition and the product was phased out, so it became a non-issue. Best of luck to you!

Comment: @Drayvock it's alright, thanks for the reply! So far I'm replacing `File.Move(...)` by `File.Copy(...)` and `File.Delete(...)`, hoping it can work somehow ¯\_(ツ)_/¯